# Constructing and sending a Soap XML Request in PHP

Tags: php, xml, web-services, curl, soap

I would like to use the ELOIS web service

**Webservice interface:**

1. To request pricing (see XML request):

   *For authentication:*

   - The broker reference
   - The broker code
   - The broker password encrypted
   - The product code to which you wish Pricing
   - Action (new, update, quote, ...)

   *For pricing:*

   - The information of the insured
   - The product-specific information
   - The reference quote if needed
2. Syntax Call :

To use the web service via SOAP, the parameters to use is :

```
Url: http://wsdev.elois.fr/Elois_Call.php
SOAPAction: getTarifs
```

3. example of an XML request

:

```
<auth>
    <reference_courtier>ELOIS</reference_courtier>
    <code_courtier>001234567</code_courtier>
    <mot_de_passe_courtier>5d7a98bddsfg465qdfs0cb1ab4887eae8
    </mot_de_passe_courtier>
    <action>devispdf</action>
    <code_produit>ACCEOPLUS</code_produit>
</auth>
<datas>
    <reference_devis>123321</reference_devis>
    <civilite1>Madame</civilite1>
    <nom1>DUPONT</nom1>
    <prenom1>Rosie</prenom1>
    <date_naissance1>1970-02-01</date_naissance1>
    <adresse1>25, rue Buffon</adresse1>
    <code_postal1>75017</code_postal1>
    <ville1>Paris</ville1>
    <telephone1>06 06 06 06 06</telephone1>
    <email1>mail@mail.fr</email1>
    <perte_emploi1>non</perte_emploi1>
    <dos_psy1>non</dos_psy1>
    <chargement1>T30</chargement1>
    <profession1>assureur</profession1>
    <caution1>emprunteur</caution1>
    <franchise1>90</franchise1>
    <projet>travaux</projet>
    <pret1Montant>100000</pret1Montant>
    <pret1Quotite1>100</pret1Quotite1>
    <pret1Garantie1>dcptia66</pret1Garantie1>
    <pret1Duree>240</pret1Duree>
    <pret1DiffAmor>0</pret1DiffAmor>
    <pret1Taux>4</pret1Taux>
    <pret1TypeTaux>fixe</pret1TypeTaux>
    <date_effet>2014-09-25</date_effet>
    <typePret1>Amort</typePret1>
</datas>
```

response returned by the web service

```
<DEVIS>
<IDENTIF>
    <code_courtier>00123456</code_courtier>
    <code_produit>ACCEOPLUS</code_produit>
    <reference_devis>1234567</reference_devis>
</IDENTIF>
<ERROR>
</ERROR>
<TARIFS>
    <pret1>
        <montant>500000</montant>
        <quotite>100</quotite>
        <duree>160</duree>
        <DCPTIA>4422.79</DCPTIA>
        <ITTIPTIPP>3184.44</ITTIPTIPP>
        <PE>0</PE>
        <fraisAdhesion>176</fraisAdhesion>
        <mensualite>47.5451875</mensualite>
        <coutTotal>7607.23</coutTotal>
        <tauxAnnuelMoyen>0.1141</tauxAnnuelMoyen>
    </pret1>
    <pret2>
        <montant>120000</montant>
        <quotite>100</quotite>
        <duree>240</duree>
        <DCPTIA>1920</DCPTIA>
        <ITTIPTIPP>1280</ITTIPTIPP>
        <PE>0</PE>
        <fraisAdhesion>176</fraisAdhesion>
        <mensualite>14.295833333333</mensualite>
        <coutTotal>3431</coutTotal>
        <tauxAnnuelMoyen>0.143</tauxAnnuelMoyen>
    </pret2>
</TARIFS>
<PDF>
    <libelle>DevisACCEOPLUS</libelle>
    <url>http://www.elois.fr/modules/acceoplus/tmpdevis/WS145464549475.pdf
    </url>
</PDF>
```

I would like to create a php script that sends a SOAP XML request to web service and receive the response

I tried this script :

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', true);

$test = 'xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance&#8221; xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema&#8221; xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"&gt;
<soap:Body>
 <auth>
    <reference_courtier>ELOIS</reference_courtier>
    <code_courtier>001234567</code_courtier>
    ...
    <date_effet>2014-09-25</date_effet>
    <typePret1>Amort</typePret1>
</datas>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>';

//Change this variables.
//$location_URL = 'http://write_your_location_url.asmx';
//$action_URL = 'http://write_your_action_to_perform_url.asmx&#8221';

$location_URL = 'http://wsdev.elois.fr/Elois_Call.php';
$action_URL = 'getTarifs';

$client = new SoapClient(null, array(
'location' => $location_URL,
'uri'      => '',
'trace'    => 1,
));

try{
$order_return = $client->__doRequest($test,$location_URL,$action_URL,1);
//Get response from here
print_r($order_return);
}catch (SoapFault $exception){
var_dump(get_class($exception));
var_dump($exception);
}

?>
```

The web service returns me this error :

```
SOAP-ENV:ClientBad Request
```

Comment: What code did you come up so far?

Comment: @hennes I update my request